# C4F RoundButton content appears on image

Tags: xaml, button, windows-phone-8, toolkit

Tried adding a Coding4Fun RoundButton to my WP8 XAML. Looked around and copied from samples (i.e. [this site](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/getting-started-with-coding4fun-button-controls)), but despite the nice images I see everywhere, the text is displayed on top of my icon: [image]

The XAML code is:

```
<c4f:RoundButton x:Name="buttonShrtn" Click="buttonShrtn_Click" ImageSource="Assets/Images/icon-button-32.png" FontSize="18" Content="Shrtn" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

I just can't find a similar case anywhere. Could there be something else in my XAML that can cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Label` instead of `Content`.

**EDIT**

> RoundToggleButton, RoundButton, OpacityToggleButton, Tile, and ImageTile content property shifted to Label property. ([geekchamp](http://www.geekchamp.com/news/coding4fun-toolkit-new-v2-released-with-support-for-windows-phone-and-windows-8))

[Toolkit description](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/coding4fun-windows-phone-toolkit).

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Couldn't find this anywhere. Where's the documentation for this?

Comment: Try http://coding4fun.codeplex.com where there is a sample app + documentation :-)